# Rebasing and debugging

Tags: rebase, ida

So usually when I debug with IDA I don't come across any issues; however, with this one particular process (which is 9.9 MB in size before modules) IDA insists it rebase every single time it starts the process, which freezes IDA and forces me to wait a good 20-30 minutes before it actually starts.

Why does it do this, and can I somehow disable this? I'm new-ish to advanced debugging such as this so rebasing only makes a little sense to me.

Comment: could you provide a bit more context?, like what operating system, maybe a link to the executable you are trying to debug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case anyone else finds this page like I did, this can also be caused if the DLL's preferred entry point is already in use it must rebase it before it can continue.

To correct this you can use the ReBase.exe tool that comes with the windows SDK (or visual studio)

`ReBase.Exe -b 7600000 myBadBasedDll.dll`
so that will reset the base of the dll to 0x7600000. You then must do the rebase in IDA one last time to make your idb in sync (or make a new idb after you rebase)

`Edit->Segments->Rebase Program...`

In the new menu check the boxes for `Fix up Program` and `Rebase the whole image` and it should be good to go.

Comment: This is more relevant. Marking as answer.

Comment: @Remko When working with DLLs you are mapping the DLL's address space in to your EXE's address space. If you are loading multiple DLLs two DLLs could have the same "Preferred address". When that happens the 2nd DLL to load gets a random available address. If that 2nd DLL is the one you are decompileing IDA will need to move it's base address for your decompiled code every time it runs.

Comment: Hey, so how would one find out whether a dll has a conflicting entry point or not?

Comment: in my case I'm trying to debug executable, not DLL.. since executable offset is always zero(?), IDA shouldn't rebase anything, but rebase still happens

Comment: @user24601 - thanks to ASLR, executables are loaded into random places within their own address space. Prior to that, it was a standard 0x400000.

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered by Will Donohoe on 31-05-2013. The website at the time of access is https://will.io/blog/2013/05/31/disable-aslr/

As explained on the site, the problem arose (at least in my case) as a result of **Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR)**. ASLR is enabled when the **DllCharacteristics** field of the **PE Optional Header** contains the mask `IMAGE_DLL_CHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE` which has a value of `0x0040`.

In my case the **DllCharacteristics** field was `0x8160` so clearly the `0x0040` mask was present.

The recurrent rebasing problem was corrected thus by removing the `0x0040` mask. Setting the **DllCharacteristics** field to `0x8120` or `0x8100` did the trick for me.

**NB:** The **DllCharacteristics** field can be located at an **offset of 0x5E** from the beginning of the **PE Signature Offset** when using a **Hex Editor**.